# Confidence intervals vs. standard deviation

Tags: confidence-interval, standard-deviation

The 95% confidence interval gives you a range.

The 2 sigma of a standard deviation also gives you a range of ~95%.

Can someone shed some light on how they are different?

Answer (score 14):

There are two things here :

1. The "2 sigma rule" where sigma refers to standard **deviation** is a way to construct [tolerance intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_interval) for normally distributed data, not [confidence intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval) (see this link to learn about the difference). Said shortly, tolerance intervals refer to the distribution inside the population, whereas confidence intervals refer to a degree of certainty regarding an estimation.
2. In case you meant [standard **error** instead of standard **deviation**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error#Standard_error_of_mean_versus_standard_deviation) (which is what I understood at first), then the "2 sigma rule" gives a 95% confidence interval if your data are normally distributed (for example, if the conditions of the Central Limit Theorem apply and your sample size is great enough).

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the question itself, which asks for the distinction between a confidence interval and a "2 sigma ... range" (which is something that is closer to a tolerance interval).

Comment: That's not how I understood the question : it seemed to me that it was unclear to the author why confidence intervals were not always constructed using the "2 sigma rule". Maybe @Berry could edit his question to make it clearer ?

Plus, (but it might be a personal bias from being used to work with sampling) when I see $[ \hat{\mu} - 2 \hat{\sigma} ; \hat{\mu} + 2 \hat{\sigma}]$, it makes me think of a confidence interval (typically under the hypothesis of asymptotic normal distribution) more than a tolerance interval.

Comment: Confused. The answer is true if the variable of concern is a bunch of sample means, which according to central limit theorem has to be normal. The confidence interval is about +/- 2*STANDARD ERROR from the mean; I don't understand how SD will approximate SE, which also considers sample size. The question conflates the 95% of sample and 95% of sample means, and that should be addressed.

Comment: Ah, I understand your comments now. I didn't know the difference between standard **deviation** and standard **error** (not a native English speaker), so I didn't spot how the "2 standard deviation" rule had to refer to a tolerance interval rather than a confidence interval. Will edit my answer.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, in sampling, confidence intervals are constructed using ONE standard **deviation** (which is almost an unbiased estimator of the variance of the Horvitz-Thompson estimator). Hence my confusion. And central limit theorems don't always apply in this case, which is why I wanted to mention sometimes confidence intervals are not constructed using the "2 sigma rule".

Answer (score 12):

May be, it will be easier to explain, to avoid confusion.

Standard deviation:
With probability about 95% we will find every new sample in interval
(x_mean - 2 * sigma; x_mean + 2 * sigma)
what says us where to expect the location of new samples.

Confidence interval:
With probability of f.e. 95% the real x_mean value will be found in the interval
(x_mean - x_ci; x_mean + x_ci)
which shows us quality of the measurements.

"x_ci" and "2 * sigma" are two different values, because of corresponding to two different expectations.
x_ci = t * sigma / sqrt(n),
where t is a multiplier according to the used theory.

Answer (score 0):

This equation relies on the assumption that the errors are Gaussian. Also, the factor of 2 in front of the SE(β1) term will vary slightly depending on the number of observations n in the linear regression. To be precise, rather
than the number 2, the equation should contain the 97.5 % quantile of a t-distribution with n−2 degrees of freedom.